# How to join strings together within a list?

Tags: python

my task is the following

Write a menu for an online food service with the option of 4 different cuisines ie: Mexican

Each of the cuisines should have at least 5 different choices such as curry then curry sauce then hot curry and so on. It should print out the users final order with the order number.

My question is how do I had the order together and then join some of the string in the list for example: add hot to veg curry but currently it puts it in different order

Lastly to make the code efficient should I use the def function?
This is the current code.
                import random

```
            print("Welcome to Hungry Horse...")
            print("We have wide range of food choice from all around the world")
            print("We have food choices from: Indian / Italian / Chinese / Mexican")
            foodList = ([])

            drinkCho = input("Lets start with drinks. State if you would like drinks yes or no").lower()
            if drinkCho == "yes":
                drinkCho2 = input("Which drink do you want? We have option of:Coke / Fanta / Cobra / Water / FruitShoot").lower()
                if drinkCho2 == "coke":
                            foodList.insert(1,drinkCho2)
                            print("You have chosen coke.A great choice")
                if drinkCho2 == "fanta":
                            foodList.insert(2,drinkCho2)
                            print("You have chosen fanta.A great choice")
                if drinkCho2 == "cobra":
                            foodList.insert(3,drinkCho2)
                            print("You have chosen cobra.A great choice")
                if drinkCho2 == "Water":
                            foodList.insert(4,drinkCho2)
                            print("You have chosen Water.A great choice")
                if drinkCho2 == "fruitshoot":
                            foodList.insert(5,drinkCho2)
                            print("You have chosen fruitshoot.A great choice")

            elif drinkCho == 'No':
                print("Ok no problem lets move on to the staters")
            mainCho = input("Which type of mains would you like:Indian / Italian / Chinese / Mexican").lower()
            if mainCho == "Indian":
                    print("Get ready to be enticed by the rich spicy falvors of Indian cusine")
                    indCho = input("What would you like to order: curry / onion bhaji / samosa")
                    if indCho == "curry":
                            foodList.insert(indCho)
            curryCho = input("What curry  would you like: chicken curry / lamb curry/  veg curry")
            if curryCho == "veg curry":
                        print("Thats a excellent choice")
                        foodList.insert(6,curryCho)
            elif curryCho == "lamb curry":
                        print("Thats a excellent choice")
                        foodList.insert(7,curryCho)
            elif curryCho == "chicken curry":
                        foodList.insert(8,curryCho)
                        print("Thats a excellent choice")
            else:
                print("inncorrect input")
                curryCho = input("What curry  would you like: chicken curry / lamb curry/  veg curry")
                foodList.insert(curryCho)

            indSide = input(str("What do you want to eat the delicious with the curry naan bread / rice or both"))
            if indSide == "naan bread":
                foodList.insert(9,indSide)
            elif indSide == "rice":
                foodList.insert(10,indSide)
            elif indSide == "both":
                foodList.insert(11,indSide)
            spiceAn = input("How spicy would you like your curry to be:hot/medium/mild").lower()
            if spiceAn == "Hot":
                print("ooh you must a man!")
                foodList.insert(12,spiceAn)
            elif spiceAn == "Medium":
                print("That is a safe option")
                foodList.insert(13,spiceAn)
            elif spiceAn == "Mild":
                ("You don't seen to like spicy food!")
                foodList.insert(14,spiceAn)

            rnd = (int(random.randrange(100)) + 1)

            print ("Your final order", foodList ," Your order number is", rnd, "Please wait until we process your order")
```

Comment: Probably you can have dictionary with a cuisines  as a keys and list of possible additions for each as a value..

Comment: This is not a "we do your homework for you" service...

Comment: why are you guys unliking the post but not giving a reason for it

Comment: @Chrissl why do you think that clearly look at my question I have asked question regading the current code  not write the next bit of the code

Comment: @TheGodfather What do you mean by that. Have you got a example Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add items to the end of a list, you want to use

```
foodList.append(choice);
```

This way you don't need to worry about the indexing involved with `.insert()`.

That means you either have to rearrange your if statements or get better acquainted with `insert()`: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I mean like if veg curry is in the list and also hot is added to the list how do i put hot before veg curry in the list so it prints out hot veg curry

Comment: Ah, I think you may be misunderstanding the insert() function.  The number you give as input is the index the item gets placed in the list.  You've got yourself inserting each item in your choice lists in different places.  for example, coke and fanta should go in the same index, but it looks like they're going to different indexes when chosen

Comment: I think understand what i am saying a bit

Comment: If you want to use insert, you just need to make sure that you're placing elements in the correct indexes.  If you get a coke with hot veg curry, your foodList array would have indexes 0 through 3.

You would insert the drink into 0, hot into 1, veg into 2, and curry into 3.

currently, it looks like you're inserting all options into the array

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me so much @Tyler Kaminsky